# Does ReSharper handle Debug.Assert(..) correctly?

Tags: c#, debugging, resharper, assert

I my code I'm using the `System.Function` method `Debug.Assert(..)` for verify the input parameter at the beginning of a method (see following example code snipped):

```
public class TestClass : IInterface
{
}

public class Verifier
  {
     public static void Verify(IInterface objectToVerify)
     {
        Debug.Assert((objectToVerify is TestClass), "Passed object must be type of TestClass");

        // ReSharper (Version 7.1.1) marks here "Expression is always false
        if (!(objectToVerify is TestClass))
        {
           return;
        }

        // do something ...
     }
  }
```

If I comment out the `Debug.Assert` statement the ReSharper warning disappears.
In my opinion, ReSharper has to ignore this `Debug.Assert` statement, because also if the `Debug.Assert` statement is not fulfilled, the code beneath is executed (e.g. in Release-mode)

What is your opinion? Or is there a alternative implementation idea?

Comment: Does it warn if you compile in release mode/have set "release" as active config in VS.

Comment: no, it doesn't because the Debug.Assert() statement is inactive. But in my opinion ReSharper can ignore the Debug.Assert statement always, also in debug mode for this rule check. Or why not?

Comment: Resharper always takes which trace-flags that are set into account. This is a built in feature. =)

Comment: ok, maybe my question was not precise. How do you implement this code different for not get this ReSharper Warning. Because of coarse I can remove the "if" statement. But then I get an exception in release mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper is smart enough to know that `Debug.Assert()` will stop execution if `objectToVerify` is not a `TestClass`. Therefore, the expression in your `if` statement is indeed always `false` (otherwise the `if` statement wouldn't be reached in the first place).

You can work around the warning by writing something like:

```
public static void Verify(IInterface objectToVerify)
{
    if (!(objectToVerify is TestClass))
    {
        Debug.Assert(false, "Passed object must be type of TestClass");
        return;
    }

    // do something ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your tip! this work around works. What I don't understand is, why ReSharper knows that the execution will stop. Because in debug mode, i have the chance to ignore the Debug.Assert() message and than the if statement will be executed.

Comment: @rhe1980, you have a point here, but the message box that allows you to ignore the assertion is only displayed in GUI mode (Windows or Console applications). Is your code part of a class library? In that case, ReSharper cannot predict if there will be a way for the user to ignore the assertion (and since ignoring assertions is arguably dangerous, maybe ReSharper doesn't even consider that case in the first place).

Comment: Addendum to your proposed solution: I didn't realized that in your solution you will have the same problem than in the solution from my question. Because the Debug.Assert() statement always is false, ReSharper detects the "return;" statement  as "unreachable code"..

Comment: @rhe1980, ah, you're right, I should have thought of that. It seems we can only trade a warning for another in this situation.

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? Assert doesn't always stop execution so how can Resharper be "smart enought" to know this?

Answer (score 9):

No, I think resharper is wrong and the reason is simple: 
**Resharper says the code is unreachable when we know for a fact it isn't.**

Release build will *always* execute that code and debug builds will hit it if you click Ignore in the dialog.

It doesn't matter if continuing after a assert is a bug or not, it's still not unreachable code.

Comment: Resharper is looking at the current build mode.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I just ran in to this problem and solved it (cosmetically) by toggling the *HeuristicUnreachableCode*:

```
Debug.Assert(false, "type/fieldNum not processed");
// ReSharper disable HeuristicUnreachableCode
return null;
// ReSharper restore HeuristicUnreachableCode
```

Answer (score 0):

I read a `Debug.Assert` as "this expression being `false` can never happen". Resharper warning is consistent with that use. It simply believes your assertion. When the `then` part of your statement executes, your program has a bug.

But you use it for parameter validation at debug time on a public API. I wouldn't use an assertion for that. You should throw an exception in that case, and eliminate your `if(...)return`.

Comment: what I wanted to is that I get an error in debug mode but not in release mode when a customer is use it. In general I'm using the way you described with throwing an exception. But now I was wondering, if the way with Debug.Assert() could be an alternative. Because what I don't want is, that the customer gets an exception but also I dont want to hide this possible design error in my code..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236408.aspx%5C).

The code looks like this -

```
  public class Verifier
  {
     public static void Verify(IInterface objectToVerify)
     {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>((objectToVerify is TestClass), "Passed object must be type of TestClass");

        // do something ...
     }
  }
```

Works in Debug and Release mode. Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)