# Nullable checking not honored after Debug.Assert

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

My .NET6/C# 10 assemblies have `Nullable` set to `enabled`.  So a function like this will (correctly) cause a build warning:

```
object[] Foo()
{
    return null;  // generates CS8603
}
```

I have to change the return type to `object[]?` to fix it.

But today I noticed something strange.  I had a function like this but also with `Debug.Assert(false);`

```
public object[] ConvertBack(object v, Type[] t, object p, CultureInfo c)
{   
    Debug.Assert(false);
    return null;  // does NOT generate CS8603 until I remove the Assert.
}
```

This should generate the warning too but it doesn't.  Not until I remove the Assert.  Neither  in a Debug nor a Release build.  But if I remove that `Debug.Assert` and suddenly both builds correctly generate the warning.

I thought `Debug.Assert` was only supposed to be compiled into builds where DEBUG is set in the build settings.

So why is this the case?

(I checked and no, my Release build does not define DEBUG in the settings)

Comment: Check also the .csproj file for presence of `<DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>`, it determines also the compilation of `Debug.Assert`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14627842/11683

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran As I mentioned in the post, I did check for that.  it is not defined in my release build

Comment: @GSerg Yes it would appear that Resharper is just as confused about this as the compiler